# Android: How to show Datepicker for March only

Tags: java, android, xml, date, calendar

Is it possible to show dates of MARCH month only inside datepicker? eg: user can only select/view dates from march month and can't change months.

Thanks

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:calendarViewShown="true">
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: March this year? March in any year the user likes?

Comment: Any march, just in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setMinDate()` and `setMaxDate()` on the datepicker to constrain the allowed dates on the calendar, for example:

```
datepicker.setMinDate(new GregorianCalendar(2021, 3 - 1, 1).getTimeInMillis());
datepicker.setMaxDate(new GregorianCalendar(2021, 3 - 1, 31).getTimeInMillis());
```

Months in `GregorianCalendar` are zero-based, hence the `- 1`.

Note that setting these properties in XML only works for the spinner datepicker, not the calendar datepicker.